# Why is Firefox HTML5 video jumping to the end?

Tags: html, firefox, video

[My movie website link](http://noobmovies.com/detail/13/)

I have the HTML video tag referencing an ogg file, webm file and mp4.  It's working fine in IE and Chrome.  Firefox displays the video but when you click play it jumps to the end of the video.  If you click along the play line of the movie it plays fine.

I'm wondering if this is a mimetype issue, where maybe my NGINX server is not recognizing it's a Webm or ogg file?

Thanks in advance for anybody who may have an idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately my only choice was to remove the ogg file.  between MP4 and WebM I believe that covers the major browsers.

Comment: That's strange, I'm using WebM and MP4 and I still get this issue on Firefox. I added the 'AddType video/webm .webm' tag to my htaccess too but it still does this.

Comment: just curious when you get this issue did you actually remove the OGG reference in the video tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug with HTML5 video using OGG files.  The best bet is to just use WebM and MP4 videos.

Answer (score 1):

@chawk In gecko based browsers .webm and .mp4 have same issue as .ovg type video/ogg. ...seems to jump to end when started initially, or started anytime before 0:05 in the video timeline. Any one found a workaround for this?

---

Just a followup: Adding correct codecs without inner quotes to the source tags fixed the issue for me.

Example:

```
type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis"
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that I just had the same experience with webm files, but not with ogg, a year later on FF v.33. I posted about it here...

[Why is Firefox HTML5 video jumping to the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502714/why-is-firefox-html5-video-jumping-to-the-end?rq=1)

Some idiot with nothin better to do voted me down, but who cares... the point is to share experiences and solutions. I'm sure this is a firefox/mozilla issue, because the same pages and files play fine in Chrome. For now, my solution is to pre-detect Firefox, and when detected block the webm from firefox, and force it to look at my ogv file instead. The way i do that is to force the webm source, which comes before the ogg source, to be commented out as the page is rendered, when ff is detected. I'd like to try adding correct codecs for my webm files, but in a pinch what I did is a good stop gap solution. I posted it here, in response to someone else's issue with webm files on FF.

[not all webm files are playing in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465195/not-all-webm-files-are-playing-in-firefox/27454661#27454661)