# Trouble getting HTML5 vidio to play, in Firefox 33

Tags: html, firefox, ffmpeg

I'm preparing to update some old pages to HTML5, and was surprised to see that it worked in Chrome, but not the latest Firefox (v.33.1... also tried v.32). What is odd is this... In Firefox it actually WILL play IF you "coax it". If you move the video position slider to someplace beyond the start (about 5 seconds in) and THEN click play, all is well. Further inspection showed that when I click play, the file pointer was jumping to the end of the file leaving my "poster" photo intact, leading the viewer to think there is nothing else they can do. If, however, you manually move the pointer back to anyplace beyond the first couple of seconds of the file (really!), and THEN click the PLAY button, FF will play the rest of the video fine.

Sometimes i think that to the more technically minded among us, the universe doles out the weirder problems, while God laughs.

I'd suspect video file corruption, but all my conversions were made with the very reliable ffmpeg utility, and tested with VLC. Again, it works fine from Chrome, which supposedly uses the same video format. Here's a link...

FF will play the older type ogv files, so if this is one of those things where FF, now at version 33 is at fault, I'll have to detect the browser and write the order myself with a document.write(). But it would be nice to know if there is a more straigh forward solution.

Note that I have tried adding the mime types to my HTACESS file. But the fact that the behavior is the same when point my browsers directly  the file on my local machine, makles me doubt that is the problem.

http://pixyland.org/peterpan/OurWedding2a.html

And here is the page code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html > 

<html>
<head>
    <title>Our Fairy Wonderful Wedding Day... The Arrival!! 
</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/pixyland.ico" >

</head>

<body  marginwidth="10" leftmargin="10"  rightmargin="10" bgcolor="#33cc99" link="#333399"  >



<table align="center" border="1"><tr><td align="center">
<div id='vtLocation' align="center">

<video width="640" height ="480" controls poster="Imagezz/Wedding/arIMG_2280.JPG">
 <source src ="../vids/Arrival.mp4" type="video/mp4">  <!--cSafari / iOS -->
 <source src ="../vids/Arrival.webm" type="video/webm"> <!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome -->
 <source src ="../vids/Arrival.ogv" type="video/ogg" > <!-- older Firefox / Opera / Chrome -->


 <!-- download as last resort -->
 <p>If you are unable to view the video, here are some links to download <br>
  in a a few well supported video formats. You may be able to just download <br>
  and play one of these files without the browser.<br><br>
  <strong>Download Video:</strong>nbsp;
    nbsp;<a href="../vids/Arrival.mp4">"MP4"</a>
    nbsp;<a href="../vids/Arrival.webm">"WEBM"</a>
    nbsp;<a href="../vids/Arrival.ogv">"Ogg"</a>
 </p>

 </video>
 </div>
 </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoever voted down my question should really go and get a life. If someone has a legitimate problem and documents it well, what purpose does it serve to try to discourage this activity? You obviously have nothing constructive to add. I will ask my questions, will get help from helpful people, and help others when O can. And the few points you pull, me down for my participation matters not to me. Take your down vote and eat it. –

Answer (score 2):

Found this suggestion that may be worth trying

```
fmpeg -i input.webm -codec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 output.webm
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639848/1686036

It seemed to help me, although it could be something else "unusual" with FF

Comment: Thanks. I've noted this  as something I need to try  my conversion batch file, as the explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks for taking the time to answer and be helpful. I wonder if my problem is in my original AVI files! But anyway, If it works, I'll hopefully be able to discover where to add the flag during an initial conversion. For webm conversion I normally pass my in and out files in a batch file like this.....

ffmpeg -i %1 -codec:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -codec:a libvorbis %2